# iOS UIAutomation : Command line Instruments sets environment variables using -e. Is there a way to access those variables in javascript's UIATarget?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

iOS UIAutomation - Command line Instruments sets environment variables using -e. Is there a way to access those variables in javascript's UIATarget?

Comment: Why would you want to access those variables in the Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Make a shell script than generates a JavaScript file with the value of the environment variables:

```
VAR1=100
...
VARN="something"
cat >> END
const Var1 = "$VAR1";
...
const VarN = "$VARN";
END > Env.js
...
# launch instruments here
instruments [...] -e VAR1 "$VAR1" ... -e VARN "$VARN"
```

In your automation script import the generated file:

```
#import "Env.js"

/* Use `Var1`, ..., `VarN`. */
```

Save `Env.js` in the automation script directory and it should work fine.
Be careful, you may need to escape your variables to generate a valid JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. That is useful. I did something different though:

Comment: In a config file specify the required paramters. Wrote a python script that reads these parameters and prints to stdout. Read the stdout and parse in the UiAutomation javascript using function parseAllEnvironmentVariables()
{
    envvars = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/python", ["utils/getEnvVars.py"], 5).stdout;
}

function getEnvironmentVariable(varname)
{
    return (new String(envvars).substring(envvars.indexOf(varname+dlimiter)+varname.length+dlimiter.length,envvars.indexOf(dlimiter+varname)));
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically I wanted to pass in variables for the uiautomation javascript. Instead of passing the variables as environment variables I am reading them from a ini file as below.

In a config file specify the required paramters. A python script reads these parameters and prints to stdout. UiAutomation javascript reads the stdout and parses variables

test.ini

```
[JSVARS]
server_url = http://foo.com
uname = user11
pwd = secret
```

Python:

```
   import json, os;
   import ConfigParser;
   config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
   config.read('~/test/test.ini')
   for jsvar in config.items('JSVARS'):
      print jsvar[0]+":"+jsvar[1]+":"+jsvar[0]
```

Javascript:

```
var dlimiter = ":"
parseAllEnvironmentVariables()
{
    envvars = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/python",["getEnvVars.py"], 5).stdout;
}

function getEnvironmentVariable(varname)
{
    return (new String(envvars).substring(envvars.indexOf(varname+dlimiter)+varname.length+dlimiter.length,envvars.indexOf(dlimiter+varname)));
}
```

Comment: Is this more information for the question, or an answer? If this is a continuation of the question, please edit your question and paste this there. "Answers" should only be answers.